# How to handle timeout exception on Restful Web Services

Tags: vb.net, web-services, rest

I have a vb.net application and I should handle the timeout on a Restful Web Service. 
In the Web.config configuration file I set the attributes "receiveTimeout" and "sendTimeout" but what I can not understand is how to perform certain actions on the Web Service side if a timeout occurs. 
Basically if I have a timeout I should perform control operations on a database, always on the web service side. 
How should I proceed?
This is the code to send data to the Web Service:

```
Private Function SendActivityToWEBSERVICE_POST(ByVal xmlFile As String) As Boolean
Try
    sUri = "http://localhost:35299/WS/SincronizzaAttivita"

    Dim encoding As ASCIIEncoding = New ASCIIEncoding()
    Dim data() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(xmlFile)

    Dim webrequest As HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(sUri)
    webrequest.Method = "POST"
    webrequest.ContentType = "text/xml"
    webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length
    Dim newStream As Stream = webrequest.GetRequestStream()
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
    newStream.Close()

    Dim webresponse As HttpWebResponse = webrequest.GetResponse()
    Dim stIn As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim strResponse As String = stIn.ReadToEnd

    Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = New XDocument()
    xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(strResponse)
    Return xmlDoc.Root.Value

Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("Eccezione " + ex.Message)
    WriteToErrorLog(ex.Message, Environment.StackTrace, "Error")
    Return False
End Try
End Function
```

With this function I send to the web service large files. I would like to handle the timeout on the web service side in the case where the sending data fails, for example in the case of problems with network connection.

This is the interface:

```
<OperationContract>
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST",
           RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml,
           ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml,
           BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           UriTemplate:="SincronizzaAttivita")>
Function SaveDataPost(sXMLFile As Stream) As Boolean
```

Comment: Show to us the code that you use to send request to your web service

Comment: I modified the message...

Comment: What do you mean, "on the web service side"?

Comment: No, I mean that I edited the above message by entering the code you see.

Answer (score 0):

you can add timeout properties on your webrequest like this:

```
webrequest.Timeout = 200000
```

it will throw out timeout error and you can catch it.

or you can build the timer your self and you can do something if it's already timeout like this:

```
Dim boolTimeOut as boolean = false

Private Function SendActivityToWEBSERVICE_POST(ByVal xmlFile As String) As Boolean
Try

    Dim MyTimer As New Timer

    MyTimer.Interval = 600000 'set your time-out...
    AddHandler MyTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf DisplayTimeEvent ' create handler to manage the timer...
    MyTimer.Start() 'start the timer...
    MyTimer.AutoReset = False

    sUri = "http://localhost:35299/WS/SincronizzaAttivita"

    Dim encoding As ASCIIEncoding = New ASCIIEncoding()
    Dim data() As Byte = encoding.GetBytes(xmlFile)

    If boolTimeOut = False Then ' if it's already time out, and do something....
        Dim webrequest As HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(sUri)
        webrequest.Method = "POST"
        webrequest.ContentType = "text/xml"
        webrequest.ContentLength = data.Length
        Dim newStream As Stream = webrequest.GetRequestStream()
        newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
        newStream.Close()

        Dim webresponse As HttpWebResponse = webrequest.GetResponse()
        Dim stIn As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
        Dim strResponse As String = stIn.ReadToEnd

        Dim xmlDoc As XDocument = New XDocument()
        xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(strResponse)
        Return xmlDoc.Root.Value
    Else
        ' Do your thing when it's timeout in here...
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("Eccezione " + ex.Message)
    WriteToErrorLog(ex.Message, Environment.StackTrace, "Error")
    Return False
End Try
End Function


Public Sub DisplayTimeEvent(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
    boolTimeOut = True
End Sub
```

Btw, i'm not test the code.

Comment: Ok, but if it drops the connection permanently (I disconnect the network cable). I manage the timeout on the client side with the "catch" but on the server side? The function SaveDataPost never get called because I have not sent the file completely. How do I handle a timeout exception on the server side?